# I wish to find the max or the highest employeeID so that I can add 1 to it when adding new records/objects in JSON

Tags: python, json, max, element

Find the max or the highest employeeId that's currently in the JSON file.
Then add 1 to it when trying to insert new records.

I tried many different things, including `max(int(str(data.['employeeId'])))`
but I am not able to get a single max value from all the records/objects.

Code

```
with open("emp.json") as json_file:
    empdata = json.load(json_file)
    for emp in empdata:
        c = (str(emp['employeeId']))
        print(c)
```

The above code ends up giving me results as

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

I just want a function which will return 7, as that is the highest number. At the time of Inserting New Records/Objects in JSON, I can add 1 to the variable that is holding the max(employeeId), but as I have just started with JSON and Python, I am having difficulty getting the right thing done.

Comment: it will be great if you could provide some sample json data

Answer (score 1):

You can use the max function to iterate over all employeeId and get the max employeeId that way.

```
with open("emp.json") as json_file:
    empdata = json.load(json_file)
    maxEmployeeId = max(emp['employeeId'] for emp in empdata)
```

Comment: Being new to Python and JSON, I was literally scratching my head over this seemingly trivial fix. Many many thanks. It works!!!